# Overwrite file content from a specified position and truncate the rest

Tags: c++, ofstream

Imagine I've got a position `pos` in a binary file `f` and some buffer with size `n`, which I'd like to dump to `f` starting at the position `pos`. And also I want to enlarge file if its size was smaller than `pos + n` or make the file shorter if its size was bigger (drop everything after `pos + n`).

What is the standard, most correct, fast and elegant way to do that?

I understand, I have to use `ofstream`, `seekp` and etc, but not sure how to drop the rest of the file if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: The C++ standard library doesn't provide such functionality. You have to use your OS API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard c++, you'll have to

- read the file up to `pos` into another buffer
- open the file with `trunc` mode
- rewrite the file contents up to `pos`
- write the dump

If you can limit yourself to an OS specific standard, such as POSIX, you have a more efficient alternative.

- seek to `pos`
- write the dump
- `truncate` into `pos + n` length using a system call

You can write a cross platform wrapper for this functionality to support differing OS, or you can use an existing wrapper. Boost filesystem has `resize_file` which does the same as POSIX `truncate`.

Comment: I thought there should be an efficient standard way to do that, but if there is not POSIX would suit me fine. Thanks for pointing out the `truncate` function!

Comment: @mambo_sun you can also use Boost if portability is worth the added dependency for you.